# Remove Frame.__init__ in python?

Tags: python

This is my code and I want to remove the Frame.__init_ part:

```
class Black(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width, height, ):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent, bg='black')
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
```

When i remove it manually, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Black' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

I think it would be a small and silly mistake. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What makes you think you can remove it? You can't, it is the initializer for the `Frame` class that makes your object work.

Comment: If you remove it, you have to replace it by `super(Black, self).__init__(parent, bg='black')`...

Comment: @glglgl Actually, in 2.x, that won't work, because almost all of Tkinter is old-style classes.

Comment: The big question is: _why_ do you want to remove it? That's what makes your `Frame` subclass initialize properly so that it can act like a `Frame`. If you don't want that, you probably don't want to subclass `Frame`, unless you have some specific reason for wanting to confuse Tkinter's type system...

Comment: The only reasonable reason I can think of off the top of my head is wanting to be a transparent proxy for a `Frame`. But to pull that off, you need to delegate all of `Frame`'s methods explicitly. (And if you have no idea what this means, this isn't what you want.)

Comment: At this point, its clear that you're not making a small and silly mistake. If you're trying to do something very different from what you're doing, you should edit the question to explain what you actually want (why `Black` should own a frame rather than being one, etc.), and then it can be reopened and answered better.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Black` class is derived from the `Frame` class, and your `__init__()` overrides that of the base class.

You need the `Frame.__init__(self,parent, bg='black')` to properly initialize the object.

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) and read about inheritance for more explanation of what's going on

Comment: what if I WANT TO REMove that and create a frame in that class??

Comment: Anything is possible. I think you need to read about, and understand the concept of inheritance. It's important, and not terribly complicated. There's quite a good guide here: http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/

Comment: @StephannieMerok If you don't want be  a `Frame`, and instead want to just _own_ a `Frame`, that's a perfectly good design, and pretty easy to do--but don't start out by inheriting from `Frame` in that case.

Comment: @StephannieMerok OK, I think I know what you want; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to *be* a `Frame`, but instead want to *own* one, you shouldn't inherit from it. Just store one as an attribute:

```
class Black(object): # note no inheritance from Frame
    def __init__(self, parent, width, height, )
        # instance of calling its __init__ with self,
        # we just construct a Frame and store it
        self.frame = Frame(parent, bg='black')
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
```

Now, to call `Frame` methods, you do `self.frame.spam()`, not `self.spam()` and so on.

---

If you want to *fake* being a `Frame` without actually being one, only owning one, you can do that by delegating every `Frame` method and attribute to `self.frame` (explicitly, or via `__getattr__`); you can even fake `isinstance` if you really need to. But this is an advanced use case, and you have to learn a bit of complex stuff to make it work smoothly, so hopefully that's not what you want.

Comment: thnx. but i hv `game = Black(root, width=10, height=10)` `game.mainloop()` at the end of my code

Comment: so error is Black object has no attribute mainloop

Comment: @StephannieMerok Of course. You can only call `mainloop` on a Tkinter widget, and `game` isn't one, because you didn't want it to be one, so you can't call `mainloop` on it. Unless I understand why you don't want `game` to be a `Frame` object, it's pretty much impossible to suggest what you _should_ do here. Maybe it's just calling `mainloop` on the root object instead, or maybe on `game.frame`, but there are a million other possibilities and I have no idea which one you want.